# What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: grammar, articles

She says there is singularity problem in the first two parts and missing article in the third one. However I couldn't find them. What am I doing wrong here?

> "Firstly, more than 10,000 Somalian liras **are** being wasted on heating every year according to online heating cost calculator of Building Green Inc"
>
> "Finally, student productivity is decreased by 15% because the temperature measured in the library is 6 Celsius degrees higher than the ideal room temperature according to **a** research done by Helsinki University "
>
> "For that reason, this paper is going to propose three solutions to waste of heat on **^** first floor of Bilkent Library Block A"

Bold parts are problematic.

Comment: The first one is definitely correct as it is: _more than 10,000_ is a plural notion and it takes a plural verb. If your professor is claiming that the verb should be _is_, then she is indeed wrong. There are other problems with all three sentences, however, as pointed out in Area 51’s answer below.

Answer (score 1):

.#1 should be:

> Firstly, more than 10,000 Somalian liras **are** being wasted on heating every year according to **the** online heating cost calculator of Building Green Inc"

(Maybe `is` is right, maybe it isn't. But `are` most definitely isn't wrong)

.#2  should be:

> "Finally, student productivity is decreased by 15% because the temperature measured in the library is 6 **degrees Celcius** ([see ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=celcius%20degrees%2C%20degrees%20celcius&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdegrees%20celcius%3B%2Cc0)) higher than the ideal room temperature according to **(a?)** research done by Helsinki University "

.#3 should be

> "For that reason, this paper is going to propose three solutions to **the** waste (wastage?) of heat on **the** first floor of Bilkent Library Block A"

Comment: No 2, "research" is one of those thingies, "mass noun"?, that does not take number at all, ever. So "according to research blah blah".

Comment: @DavidPugh: I believe you're on to something. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=according+to+research%2Caccording+to+a+research%2C+%2Caccording+to+the+research&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccording%20to%20research%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccording%20to%20a%20research%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccording%20to%20the%20research%3B%2Cc0). But I still think (perhaps wrongly) that using 'a'  is acceptable here.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Thanks! I updated my question. Please check

Comment: Actually bold parts are problematic accoridng to my prof.

Comment: For #1, one could argue that using `is` is right too (if you treat the whole thing as an amount). But unless amount (or a variation thereof) is explicitly written, I don't think one can argue that using `are` is wrong.

Comment: Using `a` with research is uncommon at the very least and possibly wrong. Maybe drop the `a`. If you feel you need to use it, consider replacing `research` with `study`.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Yes *research* is not a countable noun ( it is like *air* or *water*) and hence cannot take the indefinite article. So it has to be *some research*, or *the research*. But so far as 10,000 lira is concerned (I don't think I would say liras, though I would say pounds or dollars) it can be either singular or plural so far as the choice of verb is concerned. I am speaking here about what sounds right to a native speaker.

Comment: @WS2: You're quite right. That's why I didn't pass any judgment on using `is`. But to say `are` is wrong here would be a bit too much.

Comment: @Area51: I had a perfect storm with my connection 3 hours ago. I had a longer comment, but it prematurely ex-post-ulated on me, as it often does. (I was going to deal with "research", being hostile to the indefinite article, just like WS2, and point out that you missed "on THE third floor".) Fell foul of the 5 minutes, then got lots of SE submission errors, then the power went out. Gack!

Comment: @DavidPugh: Bad break. Don't you hate it when that happens?!

Comment: I am returning to Europe tomorrow, and hope there not to see any more submission error messages. If you'all never see me again, the reason might be their persistence even with better broadband.

Comment: @DavidPugh: Is their any expression like bon appetit which conveys "Good luck with your internet connection"? Just kidding. They oughta invent one though.